# VSTO override Excel hotkeys inside custom task pane

Tags: excel, winapi, vsto, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to override Excel keyboard shortcuts inside a custom task pane?

For instance I would like to capture the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, but Excel already uses that shortcut inside a custom task pane, and the shortcut never reaches the KeyPressed event handler on my user control.

Other key combinations that Excel doesn't use reach my event handler just fine.

Is there a way to override this, maybe via the Windows API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) function from Windows API to set up a keyboard hook. But overriding the built-in keyboard shortcut is not a good idea. Anyway, you can read more about this and find a sample code in the [Using shortcut keys to call a function in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsod/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in) article.

Comment: Took me a while to get back to this. Yes, this is in fact exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Any specific reason why overriding the built-in shortcuts is a bad idea? I want to override them in my custom task pane (I trap messages when it has focus). Having my shortcuts available in my task pane is simply more important to me than honoring Excel's built in ones.